# How to avoid critical updates prompt when admin logs in everytime?

Tags: configuration, setup

How to avoid critical updates prompt when admin login everytime?

Comment: If you review them once, then will not be shown the prompts...does not take long to review also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is there is option or configuration to to disable critical updates. It not lack of functionality but its by design.

We should understand following points:

1. Critical updates are **critical**
2. Salesforce analyses your organisation to determine if a critical update potentially affects your customization. If your customization are **not affected, Salesforce automatically activates** the update in your organisation. So if it hasn’t auto-activated you need to resolve issues!
3. On the scheduled auto-activation date, Salesforce permanently activates the update. After auto-activation, you **cannot deactivate the update**.

So, we should follow best practice of applying Critical updates asap and make sure your code works properly with new updates.